# "python3 setup.py sdist" hangs

Tags: python-packaging

I am packaging up a python package, but the command

```
python3 setup.py sdist
```

is hanging.

Previously this worked without any problems, but now it hangs while doing:

```
/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared /tmp/tmpm0rbalgy/tmp/tmpm0rbalgy/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/_tortmodule.o /tmp/tmpm0rbalgy/tmp/tmpm0rbalgy/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/fortranobject.o /tmp/tmpm0rbalgy/f90wrap_tort.o tort.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7 -lgomp -lgfortran -o ./_tort.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
Removing build directory /tmp/tmpm0rbalgy
```

The build directory has certainly been removed, so I'm not sure why it is getting stuck here.

Comment: What has changed compare to the time it worked?

Comment: Previously it worked on my python installation, but when I tried that it seems an update of numpy (or something else has broken it, as it falls over). The hanging i see above happens for a clean python3.6 virtual environment.

Comment: Got it sorted - not in the virtual environment, but in the install on my machine. The problem was the version of f2py being used had at some point switched to the python2* version. Using f2py3 sorted it.